# Combine bing maps current location with Bing Maps REST Calculate a Route

Tags: bing-maps

Hi i have sorted how to have my current location mapped in bing

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var map;

         function GetMap()
         {

            // Set the map options
            var mapOptions = {credentials:"xxxxxxx"};


            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);

            // Initialize the location provider
            var geoLocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(map);

            // Get the user's current location
            geoLocationProvider.getCurrentPosition({successCallback:displayCenter});


         }

         function displayCenter(args)
         {
            // Display the user location when the geo location request returns
            alert("The user's location is " + args.center);
         }


      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>       
   </body>
</html>
```

I also have sorted how to have the Calculate a Route to work when i specify start / end co ordinates

```
<cfhttp  timeout="10000" url="http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Walking?wp.0=-27.491030,153.095764&wp.1=-27.476757,153.040493&o=xml&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

What i want to do is be able to combine the above 2 so that i run the current location first and then have the resulting co ordinates passed to the Calculate Route so that wp.0=#current location co ordinates#

Comment: Why did you tag this "google-maps"?

Comment: i was not given a bing maps option and was not allowed to add a new title yet i tag was required

Comment: changed the tag to bing-maps.  bing-maps-api is also available.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the Bing Maps REST services in JavaScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427607.aspx. Although it's not needed as the Bing Maps V7 control has a directions module that wraps the services for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx

To make a route call to your application, simply update the displayCenter function to make use of the Routing service using either REST or the directions manager. You can also find examples of using the directions module for Bing Maps in the interactive SDK here: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#DirectionsModule4